# How to lengthen a cube horizontally?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
\draw[red] (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle ;
\draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to lengthen the widths of the above cube. But when I change some components in the 3-tuple in the code, the cube becomes distorted. What should I do to lengthen the cube horizontally?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
\draw[red] (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,2,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,2,0) -- cycle ;
\draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,2,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,2,0) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the numbers in `\pgfmathsetmacro` rather than in the `\draw` lines. But it won't be a cube if you increase its size in only one dimension!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the relevant `\pgfmathsetmacro` although if you change only one, it will not be a cube.

I would also add `line join=round` to smooth the corners of the cube a bit as they look rather jagged. Doubling `\cubex` and altering the join produces this result:

[image: double x]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, draw=red]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
  \draw (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By way of further demonstration, here's the result of the following settings

```
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
```

[image: change all dimensions]

Essentially the `\pgfmathsetmacro` is giving you a way to change each of the cuboid's dimensions along the relevant axis.

If this isn't intuitive, you could define a key-value interface to set the cuboid's width, height and depth.

```
\tikzset{%
  cuboid/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      cuboid dims/.cd,
      #1
    }
  },
  cuboid dims/.search also={/tikz},
  cuboid dims/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cubex,
  height/.store in=\cubey,
  depth/.store in=\cubez,
  width=1,
  height=1,
  depth=1,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ draw=red, cuboid={width=5, height=2, depth=2}]
  \draw (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: key-value approach]

Or with blue shading

[image: shaded cuboid]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, draw=red]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
  \draw (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, draw=red]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
  \draw (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle
   (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
  cuboid/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      cuboid dims/.cd,
      #1
    }
  },
  cuboid dims/.search also={/tikz},
  cuboid dims/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cubex,
  height/.store in=\cubey,
  depth/.store in=\cubez,
  width=1,
  height=1,
  depth=1,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red, cuboid={width=5, height=2, depth=2}]
  \draw (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=blue, thick, line join=round, cuboid={width=5, height=2, depth=2}]
  \draw [top color=white, bottom color=blue, fill opacity=.5, shading angle=-45] (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw [top color=white, bottom color=blue, fill opacity=.5, shading angle=45] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle ;
  \draw [top color=white, bottom color=blue, fill opacity=.5, shading angle=-135] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
  \draw[red] (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle ;
  \draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
  \draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{2}
  \draw[red] (0,0,0)-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle ;
  \draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
  \draw[red] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it seems the cube becomes 3-times larger if    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]   is included after    \begin{document} .  But I was expecting to make the cube be lengthened horizontally, like a cuboid....